# Intuitive proof of interpolation polynomial existence

Tags: polynomials, intuition, approximation, interpolation, alternative-proof

### **Problem:**

Given a set of $n+1$ data points ($x_i, y_i$) where no two $x_i$ are the same, one is looking for a polynomial $p$ of degree at most $n$ with the property $p(x_i) = y_i$ for all $i∈ [0, n
]$.

### **Question:**

What is the most *intuitive* way to prove that polynomial $p$ always exists? Of course, there are many ways to formally prove it, but I'm looking for a *simple*, *informal* explanation of it.

Comment: The [proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial#Proof) for the Lagrange Polynomial is pretty intuitive. Suppose you want to find a polynomial that goes through the point $(x_i, y_i)$. You first construct a polynomial that when evaluated at the point $x_0$, it yields $1$, so you multiply that polynomial by $y_0$, thus getting $y_0\cdot 1$. This polynomial as another important property, for $x_j\neq x_i$, it yields $0$. Now you add all these polynomials, one for each $(x_i, y_i)$. Recall that each of them yields $y_i$ at when evaluated $x_i$ and $0$ when evaluated at $x_j, j\neq i$.

Comment: A degree $n$ polynomial has $n+1$ coefficients and thus $n+1$ "pieces of information." Knowing that a point lies on this polynomial gives us some linear equation in terms of these coefficients, so we should need exactly $n+1$ of these points/equations to determine the $n+1$ pieces of information the determine the polynomial.